# Não Limpar form após submit wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, formulário

montei um formulário que valida dentro da função do wordpress
porem toda vez que eu faço o submit ele limpa todo o formulário e não quero que ele faça isso
estou enviado os dados por jquery dessa forma

```
form.submit(function (e) {
        var dados = {
            'action': 'acao_validador',
            'dados': $(form).serialize()
        };
        ajaxscript = { ajax_url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' };
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,
            data: dados,
            datatype: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.class == 'success') {
                    console.log(response);
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver isso, faça que ao clicar no submit chama uma `function` que pega os valores dos inputs em questão no formulário antes de realmente enviar e depois é só atribuir os valores que foram pegos na `function` antes do envio e atribuí-los novamente no final

Exemplo que fiz:

HTML:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" value="" id="txt1">
  <input type="text" value="" id="txt2"> <br> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Try it" name="" id="btn">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
    
    var input1 = document.getElementById('txt1')
    var input2 = document.getElementById('txt2')
    var submit = document.getElementById('btn')

    submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var valueInput1 = input1.value
        var valueInput2 = input2.value
        alert('TESTE: Sim foi enviado com o submit e os valores são os mesmos de ok para ver')
    })
    input1.value = valueInput1
    input2.value = valueInput2
```

Testa ai, e espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -1):

Basta colocar no form `<form onsubmit="return false">`